# XSLT to transform XML based on tag content value

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to write an XSLT that can transform an XML like this:

```
<Companies>
  <Company>
    <CompanyId>1</CompanyId>
    <CompanyType>1</CompanyType>
  </Company>
  <Company>
    <CompanyId>2</CompanyId>
    <CompanyType>2</CompanyType>
    <ParentCompanyId>1</ParentCompanyId>
  </Company>
</Companies>
```

Into an XML like this:

```
<Companies>
  <Company>
    <CompanyId>1</CompanyId>
    <CompanyType>1</CompanyType>
    <Company>
      <CompanyId>2</CompanyId>
      <CompanyType>2</CompanyType>
    </Company>
  </Company>
</Companies>
```

How can I do such thing?

(The reason I am including the company type is that I can directly derive the depth of the node from it, meaning all the `Company` nodes of depth X will be of type Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do using a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to select the children of the current Company. This works recursively for any depth of nesting. The `CompanyType` is not required.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="child-by-parent" match="Company" use="ParentCompanyId" />

<xsl:template match="/Companies">
     <xsl:copy>
        <!-- select progenitors -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Company[not(ParentCompanyId)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Company">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="CompanyId | CompanyType"/>
        <!-- select children -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child-by-parent', CompanyId)"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```